# custom accordion disabling clicking in jquery

Tags: jquery, accordion, slidetoggle

Having trouble disabling the "active" state. Any thoughts?

So when a user click on one of the accordion tabs, I would like to have the currect active tab disabled.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".accordion h5:first").addClass("active");
    $(".insides:not(:first)").hide();
    $(".insides:first").show();
    $(".accordion h5").click(function () {
        $(this).next(".insides").slideToggle("fast")
        //$(this).next("innards").slideToggle("fast")
        .siblings(".insides:visible").slideUp("fast");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(this).siblings("h5").removeClass("active");
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you post your HTML structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Disable/hide all other accordions
2. Active/ show selected accordion